# Sin Graph Converted to Function

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking for a quick response on how to convert this graph to the form `asin[b(x-c)]+d`

I thought I understood how to get each value, but I cannot figure out which value I am getting wrong.

For D I have: `1`

For A I have: `-2` (Originally |2|)

For B I have: `2`

For C I have: `π/4`

You can view an image of the graph here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDalQ.png

The final equation I ended with is `-2sin[2x-(π/4)]+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we look to $\Im(f(x))=[-1,3]$, so there is a stretching on $y-$axis, a traslation of vector $\vec{v}(0,1)$ and a simmetry in respect to $y=0$ From hre we know that there is a $-2$ that multiply $\sin(t)$. Now, we have to determine $t$. When $x=0$, $f(0)=-1$ and so the argument of sine function must be on the form $ax+\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
We know that the maximum points are at:
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, k\in Z$$
This explains why we have $a=2$. The equation becomes:
$$f(x)=-2\sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ and not what you have written because at $x=0$, your function would be equal to $-\sqrt2+1$ and not to $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Shift x-axis up to place centrally along y-axis

$$y = -2 \cos 2 \pi x/ \lambda $$

with standard wavelength $\lambda$ seen in graph $$\lambda= \pi$$

$$ y= -2 \cos2x =-2 \sin (\pi/2-2x) $$

$$ \sin ^{-1} \frac{-y}{2}=\pi/2-2x $$

$$ 2x= \pi/2 -\sin ^{-1} \frac{-y}{2} $$

$$ x= \sin ^{-1} \frac{y}{2} + \pi/4. $$